# Comentários em bloco no bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Estou precisando comentar um bloco de código e encontrei a seguinte forma que funcionou:

```
<<COMENTÁRIO
meus comentários aqui...
...
COMENTÁRIO
```

eu gostaria de saber se essa é a forma correta de fazer isso, eu li em um site e dizia que na verdade o shell desconsidera essa string porque não está sendo usada, como se fosse um comentário mas na verdade não é.

ja tentei também

```
<# comentários aqui..#>
```

`-*- comentários aqui.. -*-`

```
:'
Comentários aqui..
'
```

mas nenhuma deu certo..

Comment: Tenta a opção **:  ' ** novamente colocando um espaço entre os dois caracteres.

Comment: Deu certo!! era a falta de um espaço depois do dois pontos, se puder coloca como resposta para eu verificar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou um espaço entre os caracteres da primeira linha na seguinte opção:

```
: '
Comentarios aqui..
'
```